# ubuntu removes my recovery partion hp notebook

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-8, partitioning

my laptop model is hp-15 R004NE it has windows 8 pre installed .few days ago i installed Ubuntu 14.04 on it and for some problem while intaling my laptop turned off and installation remain un completed on next day i again try to instal ubuntu with window 8 in a dual boot fashion but when Ubuntu installation prompt it give me following options

1. instal Ubuntu alongside Ubuntu 14.04
2. Erase Ubuntu 14.04 and reinstall Ubuntu 14.04
3. Something else

and i chose the 2nd option and now only Ubuntu loads up and when i boot from live Ubuntu usb and open G Parted it shows me only C drive of 460 GB and no other partition .where as in windows when it was running it showed me two partition C 450 GB and d recovery partition i think i made some mistake and Ubuntu removed the recovery partition and i did not even store it in usb or dvd s now what can i do ?? do i have to purchase partition recovery from ho or what or is there any option to get back my windows 8 genuine

Answer (score 0):

If during your original Ubuntu install you didn't select the "Something Else" option to configure a dual-boot system, the installer reformatted the drive and wiped the Win8 Recovery partition. You'll have to contact HP to determine what your options are to get a System disc set that will restore the Windows Recovery partition. This may again require reformatting the drive and losing your Ubuntu install in the process.